# Multiple monitor identifier

Tags: gnome, python, display, gnome-control-center, pygtk

I have a multiple monitor setup running Ubuntu 20.04 with gnome. The settings app display section shows a small pop up at the left top with a number to identify individual monitor. Is there a way to retrieve what number is shown on individual monitor programmatically?

[image: Monitor identifier]

So here the settings page shows 1 and 2 on the connected monitors. My need is to capture these numbers shown on individual monitors and their ports to which the monitor is connected. ( Example: display identified with number 1 is connected to port DP-1)